# File and Folder iterators, default sort order.

Tags: google-apps-script

Anyone know the default sort order for folder and file iterators in google's app script driveApp class?  Hoping it is modified date oldest to newest but suspect I will have to resort.

Comment: I think the default sort order last modified date, from the most recent to the latest.

Comment: Unless a Googler with inside knowledge pipes up, you won't get any better response than... what have you observed?

Answer (score 1):

The sort is by last modified, reverse chronological (most recently modified first), as Gerardo observed in a comment. One can see this order in Google Drive web interface; it's one of the sort options there.

For folders, this means modifying the folder itself (creating or renaming), not the content within that folder.